# I keep getting "Invalid constant error" on my program and I am not sure why?

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, return

This is my code that calculates ISBN 13th number but I seem to be having trouble. It keeps giving me an error on the return about invalid character constant and every time I change it, it gives an error on the method name I don't understand why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ISBN {

public static int VerifyISBN(String isbn) {
    if(isbn.matches("[0-9]+") && isbn.length() > 12){
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        char digit = isbn.charAt(i);
        int sum = 0;
        if (Character.isDigit(digit)){
            int digitValue = digit - '0';
            if(i % 2 == 0)
                sum += digitValue;
            else sum += 3 * digitValue;
        }
        else 
            return 'invalid'; (This is where I get the error)
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String TITLE = "ISBN-13 Identifier";

    System.out.println("Welcome to the " + TITLE);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String response;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter the first 12 digits of an ISBN-13: ");
        String isbn = input.nextLine().trim();

        //String isbnVerifier = generateISBN(isbn);
        //if(isbn.equals("INVALID"));

        System.out.println("The 13th number of" + isbn + " is " +
            ((verifyISBN(isbn))));

        System.out.print("Do this again? [nY]");
        response = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

    } while (!response.equals("N"));

    input.close();
    System.out.println("Thank you for using the " + TITLE);

}
```

}

Comment: `'invalid'` is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. The literal `'invalid'` is incorrect Java syntax.  A string is delimited with double quotes.  Single quotes are used to delimit single-character literals, such as `'a'` but cannot be used for strings of characters.
2. The method is declared to return an integer, so you cannot return a `String`.

If your intent is to return a sentinel value indicating that the input was invalid, you should probably use something like `-1`, which can then be interpreted by the caller as the error condition.

Or, you could define the method to throw an exception.

Comment: When I use -1 it gives me an error on the method saying that the method must return an int